# Is there any way to use custom Consumer Tag with pika

Tags: python, python-2.7, rabbitmq, pika

I am using pika to work with RabbitMQ. I have a queue with a dozen consumers. I want to map consumer information in Rabbit with my application logs. So is there any way of either getting the attached consumer_tag after a connection was established or using a custom tag generated by my app?

Thanks

Comment: why is this tagged with `python-2.7`

Comment: Well actually because I need a solution for python 2.7 if it does matter.

Comment: 10 years after they made Python2.7 deprecated you are still developing new stuff for 2.7, most likely that means you use an old version of pika and RabbitMQ